# googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: youtubePartner version: v1

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api, service-accounts

I have been trying for youtube content api and tried with the following code

```
def main():
  
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    filename='bbtv-306609-b20e12d67493.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner'])
  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)
  service = build("youtubePartner", version="v1", http=http)
```

ended up with..
[image: Result]

And i have added the following user under members

[image: Google console]

Comment: Why not use ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict?

Comment: @DaImTo Yhank you for your time, I have updated the code portion as you said, but it still get the error.
And when i pass `static_discovery=False` it building successfully but gets me forbidden error when i try this `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/assets?id=<asset_id>`, but it will work fine with OAuth 2.0 playground. Can you help me.

Comment: `*** googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/assets?id=2YJse0qgMTI&alt=json returned "Forbidden". Details: "Forbidden">`
This is what i am getting from `service.assets().list(id='<asset_id>').execute()` with `static_discovery=False`

Comment: Forbidden means that the user you are logged in with does not have permission to do what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @DaImTo It is working with postman as well as 0Auth Playground with the same user

Comment: Well its not working in your code, could be an issue with your code no?

Comment: @DaImTo All i have above code lines. can you take look and help me?

Comment: The best example i am aware of is for the Google analytics api, have a look at how its performing authorization it might give you an idea whats wrong with your code.  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py

Comment: @DaImTo i couldn't find ViewID for that example

Comment: You dont need View id thats for google analytics you just need the authorization part.

Comment: @DaImTo bro, i understood that. One thing i can explain you that with the current question example i can even extract token from my `credentials` object. But i have 2 issues as you know.
1. building service failure(working when `static_discovery=False`) is ok but
2. Still `Forbidden` is my blocker issue.

Do you have any working piece of code for this authorisation if so please help me.

Comment: I couldn't figure out what is wrong with this.

Comment: [Not a bro] but i have altered the sample for you and added it as a answer. See if that doesn't help.

Comment: If you are getting Forbidden its because you don't have access, so that's actually a good thing means your code is working your just not logging in with the correct user or you haven't set the correct scopes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230259/discussion-between-susaj-s-n-and-daimto).

Answer (score 5):

For me, adding `static_discovery=False` worked.

Comment: Yeah for me also it is working but afterwards failing with `Forbidden`

Comment: @SusajSN to fix `403 forbidden`, You need `onBehalfOfContentOwner=`

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand that. can you describe it please, I am new to this. @KarolDepka

Comment: @SusajSN https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/identify_content_owner

Comment: I have tried that but still the same Forbidden issue. @KarolDepka

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example of authorization for python to Oauth2 based upon the tutorial found [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py)

Remember you need to create [service account credentials](https://youtu.be/asrCdWFrF0A), enable the YouTube api under libraries.

```
"""Hello Youtube V3."""

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = '<REPLACE_WITH_JSON_FILE>'
   

def initialize_youtube():
  """Initializes an youtube  V3 service object.

  Returns:
    An authorized youtube API V3 service object.
  """
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

  return analytics




def main():
  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I am not a python dev you will need to add the remainder of your code to this this just shows you how the authorization works.

Comment: This will work with Google apis you cant, connect to another api from googles auth server.

Comment: @DalmTo I mean YoutubePartner asset APIs

Comment: Assets is a method in the YoutubePartner  API yes it should work with assets.